# "Try Again On Your Phone" error—Android Wear

Tags: sms, android-wear, motorola-moto-360

When I try to send a text message on my Moto 360 (2nd gen, 2015) connected to my Nexus 6P, an error message pops up saying "try again on your phone." The text message actually does send successfully every time, but is always accompanied by this error message. How can I get this error message to stop popping up?

I've tried basic troubleshooting like restarting phone and watch, clearing Google app cache, changing default SMS app, etc.

How can I prevent this misleading and annoying error message from popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this thread at Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-wear/7sJbVqEqKXg)

It states that update is on its way. You can use install "Google" app beta version and everything will start working like it should.

Comment: I joined the Google app beta program and the try again message is replaced with success checkmarks. Awesome